# Contacts duplicated

Tags: contacts

I've a strange problem.
My phone create me some contacts in a strange way...
I've 250 contacts, my phone duplicate 200 of them 2 or 3 times every time the same and also if I delete the duplicated contacts (not sync with google) it comes back in a fiew minutes.
Why? there is a fix? Pls help me!

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is to use [Duplicate Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.accaci&hl).  **It also manages other contacts as well that are stored in your different accounts, including deleting all of them if you wish**

Deleted contacts are stored as a .vcf file in the root of sd card storage.

Its general description is:

> Simple tool to see and delete duplicate contacts. You can see a list
>   of contacts sorted by name or by number and you can select which to
>   delete. The duplicate contacts are automatically selected. The removed
>   contacts are saved on vcf file on sdcard.

From experience this is one of the very few  applications that serves its purpose - to delete and **NOT** to merge contacts.

Comment: I tried this application, but it missed many duplicate contacts. I need something that can handle spaces and dashes in phone numbers, or even just detects duplicate names.